# MySQL automatic string to integer casting in where clause?

Tags: mysql, sql

I am not new to MySQL but a strange situation happened in my code today coincidently which got me surprised. Can someone explain why this gives me identical results?

```
SELECT * FROM `products` WHERE id = 12
```

and

```
SELECT * FROM `products` WHERE id = '12ABC'
```

In both cases I get the same result with the same record being selected. I would expect that second one would return me nothing?! My ID field is int(11) unsigned with auto_increment flag turned on.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From MySQL docs:

> When an operator is used with operands of different types, type conversion occurs to make the operands compatible

[Documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/type-conversion.html)

So basically, `'12ABC'` is cast to `12`.

Comment: Dear lord :-). Can this be disabled or should I explicitly say do not convert somehow?

Comment: @PrimozRome: It seems that it is not possible to suppress this behaviour.

Comment: This is horrendous behavior. Is it still the case that this can't be turned off and made more strict?

Answer (score 1):

MySQL has to make a conversion to make a compare betwen 2 different types. It tries to make the string to an int and get the digits from the string starting from the beginning.

It you had for instance

```
'ABC12'
```

the result of the string conversion to int would be `0`