# Mysql query select wrong record

Tags: mysql, select

I have a table users as,

```
id    name     status
---------------------
1     user1      1
2     user2      1
3     user3      1
```

When I run this query it will select the record with id 2. Why this happened? I need to select record with id 2 when only the id is 2. I did the query like,

```
SELECT *
FROM (
`users`
)
WHERE `id` = '2a290cf764371';
```

How can I fix this issue?

Comment: There is an implicit type conversion. This means `'2a290cf764371'` is converted to `2` and then compared to `id`. To solve the problem you have to add some type checking validation on the client end.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [MySQL automatic string to integer casting in where clause?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33543671/mysql-automatic-string-to-integer-casting-in-where-clause)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That happens because you are checking a string against an integer, so `mysql` autocast the string to integer and the integer of `2a290cf764371` is `2`, don't do this kind of comparation, i suggest you to cast every ID to `int` before execute the query