# How to stop MySQL from casting strings to integers during where conditions

Tags: mysql

MySQL Version: 5.7.21.

I have a table called `my_database.my_table` with one field called `my_code` that is of type `VARCHAR(25)`.

I have the following entries in my table:

```
my_code
'1234'
'1234-1'
'1234-2'
```

When I run `SELECT my_code FROM my_database.my_table WHERE my_code = 1234;` it will return all 3 records instead of just the record with a `my_code` of `'1234'`.

I believe this is happening because both `'1234-1'` and `'1234-2'` are being cast to `1234` and therefore passing my where condition.

I understand that are ways to navigate around this issue such as `CONCAT(1234, '')`, but was wondering if there is a way to prevent this scenario from occuring in the first place.

**EDIT:**

To clarify the lack of single quotes around `1234` in my example query is intended. This is a question about how to prevent MySQL's default casting behaviour without modifying the value in the query.

Comment: Try quoting "1234".

Comment: If your column is of type string, you should use string comparison, for example: `SELECT my_code FROM my_database.my_table WHERE my_code = '1234';` or `SELECT my_code FROM my_database.my_table WHERE my_code like '1234';`

Comment: I'm aware that single quoting values will stop this behaviour, but I'm wondering if there is a way to prevent the casting problem that I've described. The lack of quotes in my example query is intended.

Comment: Found this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33543671/mysql-automatic-string-to-integer-casting-in-where-clause.

Comment: @chillcaw use `CAST AS STRING`

Comment: @D.Smania This question you've linked is asking for an explanation of this behaviour, it's not a question about preventing it, nor does it come up with a solution to preventing it.

Comment: Did you read all the commentaries, there is one that says: "_It seems that it is not possible to suppress this behaviour_"

Comment: Try: `... WHERE my_code like 1234;`.

Comment: Give a read and a try to this configuration: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/sql-mode.html#sql-mode-strict. But it say that if enabled, on SELECT statements a warning (not an error) will be produced if invalid types are used.

Answer (score 0):

When an operator is used with operands of different types, type conversion occurs to make the operands compatible. Some conversions occur implicitly. For example, MySQL automatically converts numbers to strings as necessary, and vice versa.

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/type-conversion.html