# Comparing Numeric With Alpha Numeric

Tags: mysql

I am running the following query

```
SELECT * FROM `student` WHERE '123sks'=123
```

And its returning true and I am confused why?

I am using 5.7.24 - MySQL Community Server (GPL)

What should i do if i want to comape '123sks' with 123 so that it results in false.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [MySQL automatic string to integer casting in where clause?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33543671/mysql-automatic-string-to-integer-casting-in-where-clause)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From: [Type Conversion in Expression Evaluation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/type-conversion.html)

> When an operator is used with operands of different types, 
>  type
>   conversion occurs to make the operands compatible. 
>  Some
>   conversions occur implicitly.

To get the idea of the how MySql makes these type conversions try these explicit conversions:

```
SELECT 
  cast('123abc' as unsigned),
  cast('1abc23' as unsigned),
  cast('abc123' as unsigned)
```

will have this result:

```
| col1 | col2 | col3 |
| ---- | ---- | ---- |
| 123  | 1    | 0    |
```

You may have guessed that for any string that you try to convert to an integer, 
the result is the integer value that consists of the starting numerical chars of the string if there are any, or 0 if there are not. 
So in your case `'123sks'` is converted (implicitly) to `123`. 
To get `FALSE` from the comparison, convert `123` to string:

```
WHERE '123sks' = cast(123 as char(10))
```

Comment: What should i do if i want to comape '123sks' with 123 so that it results in false.

Comment: You can't get false in this case. MySql does an implicit conversion when you do a straight comparison. But why should you compare a string with a number?

Comment: thanks for answering i was just trying to compare an auto increment value with a form submit <input type="text"> but now i will be using <input type="number">